# jquery colorbox callback value on close

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I need some help on how I can implement a colorbox callback,,, NOt sure how to do this.

I have a form that pops up in a colorbox modal window when a user clicks on an 'add image' button on a parent form. User selects or uploads images from this form (called filemanager)  and at the moment I have a script in that form that populates the parent form before colorbox closes. This method works.

However I know want to keep re-using this filemanager in other pages so this method is no longer practical so I'm trying to re-engineer so that the form returns the value of the item uploaded and let the parent form handle what needs to be updated in the form - making my filemanager a bit more universal for my app.

I found a post that customizes the close method of colorbox:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var originalClose = $.colorbox.close;
    $.colorbox.close = function(){
        var response;
        if($('#cboxLoadedContent').find('form').length > 0){
           response = confirm('Do you want to close this window?');
           if(!response){
              return; // Do nothing.
           }
        }

        alert(filename); 
        //do something before close
        originalClose();
    }; 

    $('#add-image').click(function(event) {
        $.colorbox({href:"/filemanager/"});
        return false;
    });
});
```

In the modal form there's a script variable there called 'filename' which I thought I could simply reference - in my test here it's undefined - which makes sense and expected as the cope of 'filename' is not global.

What's the best way to retrieve a value from the modal form (that exists as a javascript variable? Do I need to think about a global variable?

Is there a way for colorbox to pass back a value in it's close callback?

Are there alternatives to colorbox that can pull an ajax form and return a value?

Confused and unsure of the way to go.

Thanks

Comment: an what about "onClosed" event? http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: Hi. I'm using onClosed so when colorbox closes it carries out the script there. I'd like though for colorbox to return a value to this onClosed so I know what the user selected. At the moment I'm using a temp hidden element in the main page and ref that but doesnt seem very elegant and wondered if there was a way to call colorbox as a function for it to then return something to the calling script

Answer (score 0):

You can write a publicMethod like the following in the colorbox plugin and then call that publicMethod in the onClosed event of your call to retrieve the data.

In the colorbox plugin, do the following changes:

```
publicMethod.get_selected_files = function() {
// You can store all the selected files in an array which will be defined as the global variable inside colorbox plugin 
    return selectedFiles;
}
```

In your call, where you are invoking the colorbox, add the onClosed event as follows:

```
onClosed:function(){
    $.colorbox.get_selected_files();
}
```